# optimise the filterpredicate to support angular mat table with data source more than 80k records

Tags: html, angular-material, angular8

I created an angular mat table with  100 records in its data source, I applied a filter predicate function across all the data to support complex search queries, basically search by columns using "AND" as default clause
[image: data table with records]
search queries supported include:

- levi (any simple string that search across all the records , along all the columns)
- color = gray (column based search , that search across mentioned column name )
- color = gray AND name = jasper (search a specific entries by combining different column name using AND")

The filter Predicate works well when records are less(2k), but it takes time n makes browser hang when records are gradually increasing(20k-80k).I would like to know if the  logic I implemented  in filter Predicate can be optimized to support huge number of records or alternatively not cause browser to hang up.

And
[Here is the link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-z9bcz5?file=src/app/app.component.ts)